# Object field becomes null while doing a put in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I've run into a strange issue, where when I do a PUT using angular $resource, a field for a newly added object becomes null. The data is a bunch of nested objects. When the user drags a list item to another list, that item is pushed onto the associated object in the data and the user is prompted to add 'Comments'. After which, the 'Comment' field is updated correctly. Now, if the user presses the 'Save' button, I do a PUT to update the object on the backend. When the page is refreshed, the newly added object appears, but its comments field is null. I've looked at the data just before the PUT and the 'Comments' field is still populated as expected, but when I view the PUT XHR in Chrome, the 'Comments' field is null. The strange thing is that when new objects like this are added, a number of fields, like the 'Comments' field are populated, but only the 'Comments' field becomes null. I hope someone can explain this to me. Here is some sample code:

Original object before DnD operation:

```
myData = [
  {
    Field1: 'Data',
    Field2: 'Data',
    Comments: 'Data',
  }
  {
    // More objects like this
  }
]
```

After DnD:

```
[
  {
    Field1: 'Data',
    Field2: 'Data',
    Comments: 'Data',
  },
  {
    // More objects like this
  },
  {
    Field1: 'Data',
    Field2: 'Data',
    Comments: 'New comments',
  }
]
MyService.http.update({
                    data1ID:myData.data1ID,
                    data2ID: myData.data2ID
                }, myData).$promise.then(function() { // Here the Comments field is still populated


                    myData.isDirty = false;
                };
```

In the PUT XHR, I see this after prettifying:

```
    [
{
 Field1: 'Data',
 Field2: 'Data',
 Comments: 'Data',
},
{
// More objects like this
},
{
 Field1: 'Data',
 Field2: 'Data',
 Comments: null, // What gives?
}
]
```

Here is my $resource call:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyDataService', function ($resource, $window) {

    return {

        http: $resource(myUsualURLForGETsANDPOSTs, {
            data1ID: '@data1ID',
            data2ID: '@data2ID',
            data3ID: '@data3ID'
        }, { //parameters default
            update: {
                url: myPUTURL,
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            post: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        })

    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. I was misreading the XHR data in Chrome. The field was not actually null, but was indeed populated with the expected data. It was the return data that had the empty field. In other words, we had a problem on the backend where it wasn't properly saving all the fields that were being sent and the response to the PUT was bad.